# Material-UI Form and React Testing Library Required Form Fields

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have an MUI form that I want to test. All the form fields are required and I want to test that using @testing-library/react

Here's the form:

```
<form id='xml-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div
        <FormControl required={true}>
          <InputLabel required={true}>Name</InputLabel>
          <Input
            id='firstName'
            data-testid='required-firstName'
            required={true}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </div>
      <div>
        <TextField
          id='lastName'
          data-testid='required-lastName'
          required
          label='Last Name'
          style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}
        />
      </div>
      <Button
        type='submit'
        form='xml-form'
        color='primary'
        variant='contained'
        style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}
      >
        Generate XML
      </Button>
    </form>
```

And here's how I'm testing it:

```
test('All fields are required', () => {
  render(<XMLForm />);
    expect(
      getByTestId(document.documentElement, 'required-firstName')
    ).toBeRequired();
  expect(
    getByTestId(document.documentElement, 'required-lastName')
  ).toBeRequired();
});
```

The test fails at the first form field. Regardless of if I use `<TextField />` or `<FormControl />`, the rendered DOM elements don't seem to have the required field and I have no idea why.

```
Received element is not required:
      <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl" data-testid="required-firstName" required="" />

       7 |     expect(
       8 |       getByTestId(document.documentElement, 'required-firstName')
    >  9 |     ).toBeRequired();
         |       ^
      10 |   expect(
      11 |     getByTestId(document.documentElement, 'required-lastName')
      12 |   ).toBeRequired();
```

Comment: Looks like the issue from the `required` attribute on `<div class="MuiInputBase-root ..." />` which doesn't make sense instead of an real `<input />`. But not sure why have you done that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `data-testid` to `inputProps` when using [`<Input />`](https://material-ui.com/api/input/#props) or [`<TextField />`](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props):

```
<form id='xml-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <div
    <FormControl required={true}>
      <InputLabel required={true}>Name</InputLabel>
      <Input
        id='firstName'
        inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'required-firstName' }}
        required={true}
      />
    </FormControl>
  </div>
  <div>
    <TextField
      id='lastName'
      inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'required-lastName' }}
      required
      label='Last Name'
      style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}
    />
  </div>
  <Button
    type='submit'
    form='xml-form'
    color='primary'
    variant='contained'
    style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}
  >
    Generate XML
  </Button>
</form>
```

Alternatively, I believe you can use the [`getByLabelText()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bylabeltext/) query. For your two elements of interest, it would be:

```js
test('All fields are required', () => {
  render(<XMLForm />);
  expect(
    getByLabelText(document.documentElement, 'Name')
  ).toBeRequired();
  expect(
    getByLabelText(document.documentElement, 'Last Name')
  ).toBeRequired();
});
```